# updating only null mysql fields using python

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, isnull

I am facing this kind of problem:

I have a lot of cvs files that are not in normalized format.
Here is an example:

```
"VarName";"TimeString";"VarValue";"Validity";"Time_ms"
"Data_block_1_HC1_sec_voltage";"02.07.2015 14:16:56";3,740281;1;42187595088,2176
"Data_block_1_TC1.1";"02.07.2015 14:17:56";1319,3;1;42187595782,6042
"Data_block_1_TC1.2";"02.07.2015 14:17:56";1319,8;1;42187595782,6042
"Data_block_1_TCF1.1";"02.07.2015 14:17:56";513,9;1;42187595782,6042
"HC1_HC1_output";"02.07.2015 14:17:56";0;1;42187595782,6042
"Data_block_1_HC1_sec_cur";"02.07.2015 14:17:56";1782,873;1;42187595782,6042
"Data_block_1_HC1_power";"02.07.2015 14:17:56";6,68997;1;42187595782,6273
"HC1_HC1_setpoint";"02.07.2015 14:17:56";1320;1;42187595782,6273
"Data_block_1_HC1_sec_voltage";"02.07.2015 14:17:56";3,74994;1;42187595782,6273
"Data_block_1_TC1.1";"02.07.2015 14:18:56";1319,3;1;42187596477,0023
"Data_block_1_TC1.2";"02.07.2015 14:18:56";1320;1;42187596477,0023
"Data_block_1_TCF1.1";"02.07.2015 14:18:56";514,2;1;42187596477,0023
"HC1_HC1_output";"02.07.2015 14:18:56";0;1;42187596477,0023
"Data_block_1_HC1_sec_cur";"02.07.2015 14:18:56";1779,488;1;42187596477,0023
"Data_block_1_HC1_power";"02.07.2015 14:18:56";6,672971;1;42187596477,0255
"HC1_HC1_setpoint";"02.07.2015 14:18:56";1320;1;42187596477,0255
```

Exactly 8 variables has the same timestamp.

This is my code that I use to form the data:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
import os

from glob import glob
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, ForeignKey

i=1
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root@localhost/test',echo=False)
conn = engine.connect()
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
data_dir = ''


sql_values_list = list()


for file_name in glob(os.path.join(data_dir, 'HC10.csv')):
    with open(file_name, 'rt') as f:
        #data_file=open('HC10.csv','rU')
        reader=csv.DictReader(f,delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
        data=defaultdict(lambda:[None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None])
        fruit_to_index = defaultdict(lambda:None,{'Data_block_1_HC1_sec_voltage':0,'Data_block_1_TC1.1':1,'Data_block_1_TC1.2':2,'Data_block_1_TCF1.1':3,'HC1_HC1_output':4,'Data_block_1_HC1_sec_cur':5,'Data_block_1_HC1_power':6,'HC1_HC1_setpoint':7})
        for row in reader:
            if fruit_to_index[row['VarName']] != None:

                data[datetime.strptime(row['TimeString'], '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')][fruit_to_index[row['VarName']]] = float(row['VarValue'].replace(',', '.'))
                i=i+1
                if i==2:
                    for key, value in data.items():
                        if value !=
                        sql_values_list.append((key, value[0], value[1], value[2], value[3], value[4], value[5], value[6], value[7]))
                        i=3
                        print(sql_values_list)
        f.close()
```

data outputs this dict:

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x038C26F0>, {datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 15, 15, 1, 33): [4.034867, 1324.1, 1325.0, 533.7, 0.0, 1922.136, 7.755563, 1325.0], datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 15, 15, 4, 33): [4.034867, 1324.1, 1325.0, 533.7, 0.0, 1930.6, 7.794376, 1325.0],....
```

Here is my problem:

Since one timestamp with its variables can be in multiple files (each file has approximately 12 000 rows) and there are more than 300 files I dont want to process them all at once. Its memorz consuming and this wouldnt help me much because new timestamps are appended to new files each minute. For better understanding here is an example:

Imagine I processed one file (cca 12 000 rows) and the output for one time stamp can be something like this: `datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 15, 15, 1, 33): [4.034867, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0.0, 1922.136, NULL, 1325.0]`

I want to insert it into mysql. The next time I run the script on different file. My output can be following:

`datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 15, 15, 1, 33): [NULL, 1324.1, 1325.0, 533.7, NULL, NULL, 7.755563, NULL],`

note that there are always 8 variables for one timestamp so  there cant be something like two differnet values for each  timestamp.

The result after update should be:

```
datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 15, 15, 1, 33): [4.034867, 1324.1, 1325.0, 533.7, 0.0, 1922.136, 7.755563, 1325.0],
```

I need to update mysql db for given timestamp (primarykey in db) but only the fields that are NULL. Because on casual update I would rewrite stored variables with NULL values.

I know there is a sql statement for this called `ISNULL` or `coalesce`. 
But I have to do this in python. I am using vesrion 3.4 and pyMysql as connector with sqlalchemy. I know that sqlalclhemy can do the update but there is nothing like isnull. Please help because this is very important for me and my python knowledge is very low. Maybe there can be another solution how to do it without update but It seems difficult for me. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: there could me maybe a solution using statement insert on duplicate key update but I should set to write only to columns for which value isnt null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution today.
This does exactly what I need:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO `projections_sample` (`id`,`month`, `revenue`) VALUES (%s,%s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE month=IF(VALUES(month)IS NULL,month,VALUES(month)),revenue=IF(VALUES(revenue)IS NULL,revenue,VALUES(revenue))"
```

It uses pymysql and it updates only the NULL fields leaving existing records as they are. However I dont know how solid is this solution but this is what I need and doing it so is really important for me